# How to use filter function as a method parameter

Tags: scala

In below code the filter code is extracted to a local val :

```
val filterFunc = (x:VO) => x.getVal().equalsIgnoreCase("45")
```

I can pass this then into a filter function like so :

```
.filter(filterFunc)
```

But if the .filter function is within a method and the filter is defined outside the method I need something like this :

```
    def myMethod(p: A => Boolean) = {

    .filter(p)

  }
```

`p: A => Boolean` is part of the method signature of `.filter` method. Above code does not compile because type A is not set. How can the code be updated so that method `myMethod` accepts a filter definition as one of its parameters and then runs this code within `.filter` method ?

Edit :

When I make the change :

```
def myMethod[A](p: A => Boolean) = {
.filter(p)
}
```

I receive the error on line `.filter(p)`  :

The error is :

```
type mismatch; found : A => Boolean required: VO => Boolean
```

Comment: If you know the type of collection you're running filter against, why don't you define p type as `SomeKnownType => Boolean`?

Comment: @om-nom-nom yes that works, if add your comment to answer ill accept

Comment: If you need more generic solution you could just add generic type to your method signature `def myMethod[A](p: A => Boolean)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

def myMethod[A](p: A => Boolean)

Comment: but to pass the function into the filter method the type of A is required, since I'll be filtering based on the return value of VO.getData . Using your method does this mean I need to cast A to VO ?

Comment: No. p is a function that takes an 'A' and returns a Boolean. A is a parameterized type, which means 'A' doesn't really exist. You can tell this because 'A' is in square brackets before the parameter list. 'A' will be whatever you need it to be. So, if you pass in a function that takes a VO and returns a Boolean, it will work.

https://www.google.com/search?q=parameterized+types+scala

Comment: can you check my question update as the Scala compile seems to not allow this ?

Comment: Your filter function requires a VO. If you can't turn A into a VO, and you can't change filter into a parameterized type (instead of VO), then you've got to just use VO instead of A.

Answer (score 0):

As already said in comments: If you know the type of collection you're running filter against, why don't you define p type as `SomeKnownType => Boolean`?

Comment: can you check my question update as the Scala compile seems to not allow this ?